# Karate - How to get feature file name through java

Tags: karate

I can obtain feature file name on JS/Feature file perfectly fine using `karate.info.featureFileName;` however I am wondering how to obtain the feat on java file?

I have the need to use custom execution hook for `beforeStep`

So far I have come up with this:

```
        System.out.println(context.getFeatureContext().feature.getName());
```

However it is printing the feature name instead of the file name `FindStoryByID`. It returns:

`Test GraphQL Find Story By ID`

Is it possible to get the feature file name through the context?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
     File f = null;
     f = context.getFeatureContext().feature.getPath().toFile();
     String name = f.getName();
```